# counting at the end of the pipeline aggragation - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

suppose I did some aggregation work where I get some cursor that point to documnets with one filed "results".

```
 { result: 0}
 {result:1}
 {result: 3}
```

I would like to know how many  documents have results bigger than 0?
can I add it to the aggregation pipeline and not to iterate the cursor on my side?

something like:

```
          db.aggregarte(..... ,{count (result>0)})
```

where count will be the last step.

also, will I get cursor anyway?

Comment: will I get a cursor ? how can I get dbobject or int?

Comment: Try `{$group:{_id:null, count:{$sum:{$cond:[{$gt:["$result", 0],1,0}]}}}}`. I've removed my old comments. Please remove all your old comments.

Comment: yeah. pls explain why you think otherwise.

Comment: Please update your question with details. Remove all the comments.

Comment: how can we create the part {$gt:["$result", 0],1,0} in java?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42879552/2683814) is one example. See if you use it.

Comment: thanks will look at it

Comment: it's not the same case, here you have 2 elements in dbbject which are not dbobjects... ( 0 and 1)

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong

Comment: Can I see your code ?

Comment: it should be: $cond:[{$gt:["$result", 0]}, 1,0 ]} , no? instead of {$cond:[{$gt:["$result", 0],1,0}]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164165/discussion-between-veeram-and-ohad).